# How to back-pressure TCP client

Tags: vert.x

I have a Vert.x NetServer, and accept one connection from client side, suppose I pause socket ReadStream, then I won't receive any buffer from connection, at the same time, suppose client side keep on sending message, I am wondering whether it is possible to back-pressure client side to get halt rather than continue to send? If it is impossible, where those incoming data store? and could I check how much data was already come in but not be read?

Any helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems all your questions are already addressed by the official documentation:

https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#streams

Incoming messages are stored in the write queue. If write queue is full, you can ask client to pause with `pause()` method, and to resume with `resume()` method.

Alternatively, and this is also covered in documentation, you can use `Pipe` to handle this for you.